# How to add string as value for new column for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add string value and assign to a new column for dataframe , but could not figure it out the best way to do this.

```
Df['new'] = "my value"
```

But this is not working and I couldn't understand why, can someone please explain to me ? Or how exactly can I do this in Python using pandas dataframe ?

Comment: That looks fine to me can you add print out of dataframe before and after?

Comment: That should work, if it doesn't work explain exactly what doesn't work? Is there an error, is the column created at all, is the column created but with blank values etc.. post data that we can run to reproduce your error, also what version python, pandas and numpy are you running?

Comment: If Df is empty then this is actually working, it's just that there are zero rows...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]}
j = {'c':['a','hello','t']}
x = pd.DataFrame(d)
y = pd.DataFrame(j)
x.insert(2, 'c', y)
```